# Three vectors walk into a bar and related problems

Tags: linear-algebra

These are some practice conceptual problems I found in my textbook. I was hoping that I could share my answers to see if my approach is correct.

True/False (If true, explain why. If false, give a counterexample.)

(a) Let $\vec{u}, \vec{v},$ and $\vec{w}$ be vectors in $\mathbb R^n$
. If $\vec{u}$ is a linear combination of $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{w}$ then $\vec{w}$ must be
a linear combination of $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$.

True, because there can always be a constant that can be multiplied to a vector to revert a linear transformation if it is a linear combination to begin with.

(b) If a system of linear equations over the real numbers has two different solutions, then it
must have infinitely many solutions.

True, because a system of linear equations can only have 0, 1, or infinitely many solutions. Because two lines can be coincident (infinite), parallel (0), or coplanar (1).

(c) Let A be an n × n matrix, and let B be the same matrix with the bottom row removed and
then placed at the top. Then det(B) = − det(A).

True, because the pattern for finding a determinant is the same, but a different part is subtracted, making it the opposite sign when the bottom row is placed on top.

(d) If A is a 3 × 3 real matrix and the equation

$$A\vec x=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\
    0 \\
    0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}$$
has a unique solution, then A
must be invertible.

I am unsure how to do this one

Thanks for your help and input!

Comment: I think the first part is not quite correct. If you take $\overrightarrow{u} = 2\overrightarrow{v}$, this is a linear combination of $\overrightarrow{v}$ and $\overrightarrow{w}$. However, in this case, you might not be able to write $\overrightarrow{w}$ as a linear combination of $\overrightarrow{u}$ and $\overrightarrow{v}$. This would be the case of $\overrightarrow{v}$ and $\overrightarrow{w}$ being linearly independent.

Also, for part (d), try finding the rank of matrix if the system has a unique solution and then proceed to prove that inverse must exist.

Comment: Oh okay. Can you show me a counterexample for the first part?

Comment: Consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ space. Take two vectors $\overrightarrow{v} = \left( 1, 0 \right)$ and $\overrightarrow{w} = \left( 0, 1 \right)$. These are the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$. Now, take another vector $\overrightarrow{u} = \left( 2, 0 \right)$. This will tell us that $\overrightarrow{u} = 2\overrightarrow{v} + 0\overrightarrow{w}$, which is a linear combination of $\overrightarrow{v}$ and $\overrightarrow{w}$. However, since $\overrightarrow{v}$ and $\overrightarrow{w}$ are linearly independent, you cannot write them as linear combinations of each other.

Comment: Gotcha, that makes sense. Are parts b and c correct? I'm pretty sure b is right but I wasn't sure about c. Thanks for helping

Comment: Yes, it seems so!

Comment: Okay, and can you show me how to do part d?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(d) is true, since a solution to $\mathbf{Ax=b}$ remains one when any solution of $\mathbf{Ax=0}$ is added to it. If we want only one solution to the first equation, the second must have only the trivial solution; $\mathbf A$ is then of full rank and thus invertible.

(c) is actually false, but only for odd $n$. *Swapping* two rows or columns always negates the determinant, but when $n$ is odd the number of such swaps performed to get the bottom row on top is even, so the determinant remains unchanged.

(b) is correct by a simple argument on linear combinations of solutions. (a) is false by the argument of Deshmukh in the comments.

Comment: Can you give me a counterexample for part c? Because I did it with a couple 3x3 matrices and got det(B) = -det(A).

Comment: @JackHarold Use the identity matrix.

Comment: I got det(B) = -det(A) for that also? 1 = -(-1)

Comment: Oh never mind! I was swapping instead of moving. Sorry